# IE8 Input Element Tooltip Issue

Tags: internet-explorer-8, tooltip, html-input

I have an input element in IE8

```
<input name="aa" value="0" title="show tooltip"/>
```

The tooltip only shows up when my mouse hovers over the empty space in the input box.  If the box is filled with text, then the tooltip does not show up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem intermittently when hovering over text depending on where the cursor is.  It appears that when the cursor is directly over the center of the text you can't see the tooltip - it may be that IE puts some sort if inner element to display the text.

You can, however put a span around the input with a title attribute, and it will continue to show up even if the cursor is directly over the text.

```
<span title="show tooltip">
  <input name="aa" value="0" />
</span>
```